# Finding the list of successors of a basic block in LLVM

Tags: compiler-construction, llvm, compiler-optimization, llvm-clang

In LLVM the BasicBlock has the properties getSinglePredecessor() and getSingleSuccessor(), but I need to get the whole list of successors and predecessors of a basic block. How can I achieve this in llvm?

My code is

```
        virtual bool runOnFunction(Function &F) {

        for (Function::iterator b = F.begin(), be = F.end(); b != be; ++b) { 
        //Here I need to get the predecessor and successsor of the basic block b 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree that there is no direct property to a BasicBlock.  Instead, you can [get the terminator instruction](http://www.llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1BasicBlock.html#a5cb76a65b6524dba1493dd2b9dc3abbe) of the basic block and then iterate through its [successors](http://www.llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1TerminatorInst.html#a3aac3b6c36415a2b08f65ead9e3e51e7).

Or, based on reading the [source code](http://www.llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/BasicBlock_8cpp_source.html#l00211) to the BasicBlock class, you can create a pred_iterator and succ_iterator from your BasicBlock instance.  For example:

```
for (Function::iterator b = F.begin(), be = F.end(); b != be; ++b)
{
    BasicBlock* bb = dyn_cast<BasicBlock>(&*b);
    for (pred_iterator pit = pred_begin(bb), pet = pred_end(bb); pit != pet; ++pit)
```

Answer (score 4):

Slightly less code if you'd prefer that:

```
#include "llvm/IR/CFG.h"
BasicBlock *BB = ...;

for (BasicBlock *Pred : predecessors(BB)) {
  // ...
}
```

The snippet is taken from [LLVM's Programmers Handbook](http://llvm.org/docs/ProgrammersManual.html#iterating-over-predecessors-successors-of-blocks).